# How to send a file from a MySQL BLOB as download to the enduser?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts

How can I send a file as download to the enduser? I have implemented a form submission of a page with a column of data as session of the DB. This column includes one file which is saved as BLOB in a MySQL database.

When handling actionforward and using the mapping file for a table with CV's, I can access the file content by `cv.getFileContent()`. Do I have to send the data byte by byte to the user? How do I offer the file as a download?

Answer (score 1):

You should use servlet as download mechanism.

Submit your form to Servlet using Get or Post,then in Servlet Class implement doGet or doPost accordingly.

Using Hibernate fetch the column as byte Array.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {

    //Getting data s byte Array;
    byte[] csvFile = daoService.getFile(id);

    resp.setContentType("text/csv");
    resp.setContentLength((int) csvFile.length());
    ServletOutputStream out;

    try {
        out = resp.getOutputStream();
        out.write(csvFile);
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        out.close();
        out.flush();
    }

}
```

Hope it helps.

**Update:**

This is how I mapped the `byte[]`.

```
<property
    name="image"
    update="true"
    insert="true"
    not-null="false"
    unique="false"
    type="binary"
>
    <column name="image" />
</property>
```

Comment: Thank you for that -> how do I transfer a blob into a byte file ?? Also, when trying to implement this code, it complains that it requires a byte[] but found cvbeta (which is my mapping file for the table that holds those CV's / documents) -> I would like to know how to transfer a returned blob of table into byte, when calling getFile method of DAOservice !?!?

Comment: you will content-disposition header as well

Comment: @betstsss - it preferred  but not mandatory. In my case I'm streaming it to byte array in the client, but if you need to open "Save AS" with special file name dialog in browser then yes this is required.

Comment: @danny.lesnik, for csv it's generally preferred. btw length is consider a field for byte[]; and you can't flush closed streams [so either flish() only or flush(),then close() or just close()]

Comment: ok thank you for you answer, but i have been working with BLOB until now, as e.g. saving the file etc. . . so would you know how to transfer a blob into byte. Or is byte more desirable / preferred / better to use byte type than blob, and I should change mapping files and current functions !??  thanks for the help so far !!!

Comment: @danny.lesnik & @betstsss  -> assuming that also means I can not work with a blob -> to be offered as file download !?!? It has to be byte !?!?  thx alex

Comment: The thing is, I am just in the process of changing my existing function to upload a file e.g. to use byte instead of blob -> now i get invlaid form submissions -> argument type missmatch ! So i assume it has to do with the fact of it being a byte now. Can i not use my cv.getFileContent -> type: byte[] of java mapping file in accordance with cv.hbm file - cvfilecontent, type =binary !?